# How to declare a type inside class model?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to angular2. So, please bear with me.

What I have tried so far:

```
export class Navbar {
  name: string;
  submenu: {
    name: string;
  }
}
```

Again: I tried array and []

```
export class Navbar {
  name: string;
  submenu: array;
}
```

This is the code without submenu declaration.

```
export class Navbar {
  name: string;
}

const NAVBAR: Navbar[] = [
  { name: 'Company Data' },
  { name: 'Client Data', 
    submenu: [
      { name: 'Balance' },
      { name: 'Settlement' }
    ]
  },
  { name: 'Bookie Data' },
  { name: 'Bank Data' },
  { name: 'Journal Entry' },
  { name: 'Journal Bank' },
  { name: 'Report', 
    submenu: [
      { name: 'General Ledger' },
      { name: 'Trial Balance' },
      { name: 'Profit/Loss' },
      { name: 'Balance Sheet' }
    ]
  },
  { name: 'Control' },
  { name: 'Input', 
    submenu: [
      { name: 'Company' },
      { name: 'Client' },
      { name: 'Bookie' },
      { name: 'Master' },
      { name: 'Client Agent' },
      { name: 'Bookie Balance' },
      { name: 'Import Client Data' },
      { name: 'Chart Of Account' },
      { name: 'Bank' },
      { name: 'Bank Company' }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is the error thrown by angular.

```
app/app.component.ts(10,5): error TS2322: Type '({ name: string; } | { name: string; submenu: { name: string; }[]; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Navbar[]'.
  Type '{ name: string; } | { name: string; submenu: { name: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Navbar'.
    Type '{ name: string; submenu: { name: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Navbar'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'submenu' does not exist in type 'Navbar'.
```

Any help would mean so much to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a couple of things you will want to alter... First of all, I would suggest using an `interface` or `type` instead of a `class` because you're not calling `new` anywhere.

The other thing, is that by having `submenu: array` it is not optional and is therefore expected on every instance which will not be the case (the tree needs to stop somewhere). You can denote this by using a `?`

That will leave you with an interface like this:

```
export interface Navbar {
  name: string;
  submenus?: Navbar[];
}
```

Which will allow this to work:

```
const navbars: Navbar[] = [
  { name: 'Company Data' },
  { name: 'Client Data', 
    submenus: [
      { name: 'Balance' },
      { name: 'Settlement' }
    ]
  }
];
```

[Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20Navbar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20submenus%3F%3A%20Navbar%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20navbars%3A%20Navbar%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Company%20Data'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Client%20Data'%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20submenus%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Balance'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Settlement'%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B)

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Thanks. Can you point me where did you get documentation like that? I am searching for it since yesterday at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/.

Comment: And what if I change the submenus object key into another name? How should it be? Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! Types are a feature of TypeScript, not angular2, you can get started here reading their docs in their handbook... http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html